Determine whether this function is convex.
I saw this assertion (in the Proof of Theorem 1.2,page5) in the article J. Wang, The shifting method and generalized Turán number of matchings, European J. Combin. 85
(2020), 103057, 7, DOI 10.1016/j.ejc.2019.103057. (I have extracted the conditions.)
Claim 1. Let $2 ≤ s ≤ k + 1$, $k+1\le \ell \le  2k+1$ and $n\ge 2k+1$. Then $f(\ell)=\binom{\ell}{s}+(n-\ell)\binom{2 k-\ell+1}{s-1}$ is a convex function.
The final  aim is to prove that
\begin{aligned}
f(\ell)& \leq \max \{f(2 k+1), f(k+1)\} 
\end{aligned}
The paper says: By considering the second derivative, it is easy to check that $f (ℓ)$
is a convex function.
However, for me, this type of problem involving binomial coefficients seems to require brute-force computation, and it doesn't appear to be straightforward. Is there really a more efficient method for verification?

It's actually not too bad to compute the second derivative. We simply have to use the recurrence relation of the binomial coefficient repeatedly:
$$
\binom{n}{k} - \binom{n-1}{k} = \binom{n-1}{k-1}.
$$
Consider the first term, call it $g(\ell)$, for example. We have
\begin{align}
&g(\ell+1)-2g(\ell)+g(\ell-1)
\\
&= \binom{\ell+1}{s} - 2 \binom{\ell}{s} + \binom{\ell-1}{s}
\\
&= \binom{\ell}{s-1} - \binom{\ell-1}{s-1}
\\
&= \binom{\ell-1}{s-2}
\\
&>0.
\end{align}
Similarly, for the second term, call it $h(\ell)$, we have
\begin{align}
&h(\ell+1)-2h(\ell)+h(\ell-1)
\\
&= (n-\ell-1) \binom{2k-\ell}{s-1} - 2(n-\ell) \binom{2k-\ell+1}{s-1} + (n-\ell+1) \binom{2k-\ell+2}{s-1}
\\
&=(n-\ell)\left[ \binom{2k-\ell+1}{s-2} - \binom{2k-\ell}{s-2} \right]
\\
&\qquad + \left[ \binom{2k-\ell+2}{s-1} - \binom{2k-\ell+1}{s-1} + \binom{2k-\ell+1}{s-1} - \binom{2k-\ell}{s-1} \right]
\\
&=(n-\ell) \binom{2k-\ell}{s-3} + \left[ \binom{2k-\ell+1}{s-2} + \binom{2k-\ell}{s-2} \right]
\\
&\ge0.
\end{align}
Therefore, $f(\ell)$ has positive second (discrete) derivative, and hence is convex.

Nice, could you recommend a book that introduces these discrete derivatives (especially their definitions), including the definitions of convex functions?(as I have only encountered the continuous versions) Thank you.

@licheng You can read about discrete calculus on Wikipedia. Here’s a text on convex functions over discrete domains: https://kzmurota.fpark.tmu.ac.jp/paper/HIMSummerSchool15Murota.pdf. I don’t know any specific textbooks.
